# Confused on how to sort an array of objects in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm relatively new to ruby. I have an array called `claims`. Each elements in the `claims` array is a claim. If I do `claims[0].houses`, I get an array of houses. There are two things that I am confused on.

The first is when I type `claims[0]` into the console I don't actually see the house property, but when I do `claims[0].houses` I see my array of houses. Is houses a property of the claims object?

My second question is about sorting my `claims` array. Each `house` has a price property. So my data structure looks like this:

```
Claim[0]  Claim[1]  Claim[2]

house[0]: house[0]: house[2]
price: 20 price: 24 price: 11

house[1]: house[1]: house[2]:
price: 17 price 30  price: 28
```

What I want to do is sort my claims by the cheapest price house, so the 0th index of `claims` should have the `houses` array with the cheapest house. The 1st index of the `claims` array should have the `houses` array with the second cheapest house like so:

```
Claim[0]  Claim[1]  Claim[2]

house[0]: house[0]: house[2]
price: 11 price: 20 price: 24

house[1]: house[1]: house[2]:
price: 28 price 17  price: 30
```

To explain how I got the result above I found that the `houses` array in `Claim[2]` had the cheapest house at 11. So that went into `Claim[0]`. Then I found that of the remaining unsorted `houses` the one that was originally in `Claim[0]` had the cheapest house at 17, so it went into `Claim[1]`.

I can't really figure out how to do this in ruby.

I've tried many things including:

```
claims.sort!{|a,b| a.price.min <=> b.price.min}
```

But I get an error that says `undefined method price for #<Claim:0x0000010>`

So then I tried

```
claims.sort!{|a, b| a.house.price.min <=> a.house.price.min}
```

and again I get an error that says `undefined method price for #<Array:0x00000e7b>`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You indicated that `claims` is an array of `Claim` objects, each of which have an array of `House` objects. If that's accurate, you're not going to be able to call `price` on the array of `House` objects directly. You'll need to call `price` on a single `House` model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why was this post down voted? What should I have done to improve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it rather compactly like this:

```
claims.sort_by! { |claim| claim.houses.map{|h| h.price}.min}
```

This might appear to be inefficient at first, but is actually not because of the way [sort_by is implemented](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

---

You could also do it in two steps - this way might be slower depending on the details of your program.

First, sort each array of houses by price:

```
claims.each do |claim|
  claim.houses.sort_by! { |house| house.price }
end
```

We now know the first house in each claim is the cheapest for that claim. Then I'd sort the claims:

```
claims.sort_by! { |claim| claim.houses.first.price }
```

Check out the [documentation for sort_by!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21)

---

I haven't tested any of these, so feel free to comment if you encounter any problems or have any other questions

Comment: Note: doing the computation *inside* the sort_by! block is not less efficient, if the outer sort is only done once (and is actually more efficient as min/max is faster than a sort) because each "sort value" is effectively cached via a [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) technique..

Comment: Ah, I has assumed that the 'sort value' would get recomputed each time (it could theoretically have side effects). But that would be a pretty nasty scenario, makes sense to have it cached

Comment: Fascinating stuff by the way @user2864740, saw your edit on the Schwartzian Transform.  I believe your first comment is still incorrect though (you've got a `min` instead of a `map`)

Comment: Assuming that there is at least one house, `houses.min_by(&:price).price` (find the house with the minimum price, then get the price of the house) should be semantically equivalent to `houses.map(&:price).min` (find the prices for all houses, and select the minimum price). Although my previous comment *was* incorrect in that it used `min` and not [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by).

Comment: Ah, I see. However, `min` expects a block that takes two arguments which get compared, so the `&:price` part won't work - you're looking for `min_by`. I've updated my post to include all the relevant things we've discussed btw, thanks for the great input

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, I made a demo to sort.

```
claims = [
  {houses: [{price: 20},{price: 17}]},
  {houses: [{price: 24},{price: 30}]},
  {houses: [{price: 11},{price: 28}]} ]
claims.sort{|x,y| x[:houses].map{|h| h[:price]}.min <=> y[:houses].map{|h| h[:price]}.min}
=> [{:houses=>[{:price=>11}, {:price=>28}]},
    {:houses=>[{:price=>20}, {:price=>17}]},
    {:houses=>[{:price=>24}, {:price=>30}]}]
```

The result is what you want.

But becase I use array and hash instead of object, you can use `x.houses` instead of `x[:houses]`, and `h.price` instead of `h[:price]`.

And if you add min_price method in Claim object, will be better.

```
Class Claim
  def min_price
    houses.map{|h| h.price}.min
  end
end

claims.sort{|x,y| x.min_price <=> y.min_price}
```